# Algorithm to select representative samples for chart

Tags: algorithm, charts

Example:
I have 100 samples for some certain time period. But I can use only 10 values to draw the line chart. What algorithm I can use to calculate those 10 representative values to let the chart look similar if I'd use all the 100 exact samples to draw it.

The naive algorithm which calculates average of every next 10 samples do not reflect the peaks in the chart very well.

Comment: Unless you know something more about the input signal you won't get much better than a simple average.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [Douglas-Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm to obtain an optimal under-sampled representation.

The algorithm builds an under-sampled set starting with just the end points of the original data set. At each step the point in the original data set that's "furthest" (of maximum error) from the under-sampled representation is added to the under-sampled set. In this way the algorithm includes the important peaks in the original data set and constructs an under-sampled representation of minimum error.

Since you're only allowed 10 points in your under-sampled set you could setup the algorithm to only grow the under-sampled set to size 10.

If you have an original data set that includes too many peaks there's no way that you'll be able to capture them all and satisfy the size constraint.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 but since there can only be 10 samples isn't it a maximum of five peaks (because of the five troughs needed to separate the peaks).

Comment: 100 and 10 was only for example demonstration. In reality the number of representative values is 200 and the number of samples can be 1000 or 10000.

Comment: It seems the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm selects representative values always from the given samples. However, my requirement is weaker. The representative value can be calculated value and does not need to be one exac value taken from samples.

Comment: @PetrFelzmann: The approach should generalise to arbitrary numbers of samples in either set, so there's no issue there. You're correct in that this approach samples from within the original set - it doesn't calculate new values. At this stage it's not clear to me that calculating new values would necessarily be better. For instance, any kind of averaging will tend to smooth off the peaks - as you point out in your question. If you point out the issues with the method described maybe further suggestions can be made...